# SQL postgresql: maximum value and sum of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I need to make a query to the following table, to return the maximum date grouped by code and also make the following calculation: deb-cre (maximum only).
How would I do this?

```
code | date       | deb    | cred
-----------------------------------
4    | 2018-01-01 | 100,00 | 200,00
4    | 2017-12-28 | 100,00 | 500,00 
6    | 2018-01-23 | 350,00 | 400,00
6    | 2018-04-28 | 140,00 | 678,00 
8    | 2018-01-12 | 156,00 | 256,00
8    | 2016-02-28 | 134,00 | 598,00
```

The result must be

```
4    | 2018-01-01 | -200,00 
6    | 2018-04-28 |  -50,00
8    | 2018-01-12 | -464,00
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but I can't see how you end up with `-200` by subtracting `cred` from `deb` for  code 4. Ignoring that column therefore, you could do something like `SELECT code, MAX(date) FROM your_table GROUP BY code` or `SELECT DISTINCT ON (code) code, date FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: Thanks eurotrash, it worked perfectly (it was my mistake on -200, the correct value is -100)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` in combination with `ORDER BY` will return the first row per group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code)
       code, date, deb - cre
FROM your_table
ORDER BY code, date DESC;
```